# Verifying if a function is in an $L^p$ space

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Define $f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln x}$ for $x\ge 1$. Show that for $p$ in $[1, \infty)$, $f$ is not in $L^p$

Comment: I tried but didnt proved yet.

Comment: What exactly? You should share your results with the community.

Comment: Im not so confident with the steps I did. There is a hint which is e^t>=t^k/k! for t>=0 and k a positive integer. I dont know how to use the hint. :(

Comment: Ah ok got it. I just let t=ln x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that, $$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{(\log x)^p}dx= \int_0^\infty\frac{e^t}{t^p}dt $$ Now use the hint.

Comment: Thank you so much for this

Answer (score 0):

For all $p\ge 1$ exists $k(p)\ge 1$ s.t.
$$x\ge k(p)\implies (\log x)^p \le x.$$
Now, you can compare your integral with a divergent integral:
$$\int_{k(p)}^\infty\frac1x\,dx\le\int_{k(p)}^\infty\frac1{(\log x)^p}\,dx\le\int_1^\infty\frac1{(\log x)^p}\,dx.$$